# Intermittent Timeout Issue from Android to Web Server

Tags: java, android, api, timeout, okhttp

I am calling an API from android application. It is giving a timeout issue intermittently. Few set initial calls are always successful and then the success is intermittent. It is giving below exception.

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /:8080
>   at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:242)
>   at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:160)
>   at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)...

I am using this networking library https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking

Even, I tried with a volley but the result is the same.

---

Also, increased the timeout.

```
 OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient()
    .newBuilder()
    .connectTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
```

This also not helped to resolve the issue.

Comment: Url is corrent? Url works in browser? Port `8080` is correct?

Comment: Yes. Url is correct. It is working for few initial calls

Comment: Does it work with other `urls`? Also, please post the code of your API call in your question. You can change private parts you don't want to be public

Comment: @Philipp You can check sample code here https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking/issues/324

Comment: Can't see why you think it is a `timeout` issue. Have you found a threshold where requests still got processed. You need to narrow it down a bit further to address the problem. Maybe try http://square.github.io/retrofit/ to determine if it's a library issue

Comment: @Philipp I tried the same request with https://developer.android.com/training/volley/ and getting same kind of issue after few hits

Comment: @Philipp Also tried caliing same API 1000 times from plain JAVA code and it is working fine with average resposne time 1s

Comment: So if you exclude the issue from the library and your endpoint the only thing left is your loop(?) where you are making requests or the device from where you are making them, correct?

Comment: @Philipp Thanks. It is the issue with Andriod. I am calling API in background service.